# Why can't I use this sprite in Cocos2d/Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

In my game in objective c, I have two classes, The main ArcherClass and the person class. 
Here is part of the .m of the person class.

```
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _bow = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bpw.png"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is part of main ArcherClass.m

```
  Player *object = nil;
        CCSprite *bow;

        bow = [object bow];

        //bow = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bow.png"];
        [self addChild:bow z:1];

        bow.position = ccp(150,150);
```

The following code gets a sigbart error, because of the part I commented out. If I delete the comment, the code works fine.

Why can I not use the image file declared in the Person class? I already declared that sprite as to having that image value or whatever, but for some reason I have to re-declare the image in my main class? Why is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your "person" class and "Player" classes referred to are the same thing, this code:

```
Player *object = nil;         
CCSprite *bow;          
bow = [object bow];
```

Is going to set `bow` to `nil`. You haven't initialised `object` so any methods called on it will return `nil`.

Somewhere in your code you need the following:

```
Player *object = [[Player alloc] init];
```

It's difficult to say where without more context, but if you are sending messages to object, you need to have a valid instance of it. You don't say how the archer class and player classes are related.

Comment: I took out the nil, now im getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I've updated my answer. How many Player objects are there supposed to be? How are the Player and Archer classes related? You may need to add more detail to the question.